# Scaling a logo to be consistent between video sizes

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm now using this command to scale a logo overlay

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid.mp4 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=in_w*.25:-2[logo];\
[0:v][logo]overlay=30:20" out.mp4
```

But, sometimes the logo looks different when the input video size changes.

I want to have a consistent logo between video sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scale2ref to scale your logo according to the main video.

For example to scale the logo to 1/5 (one fifth) of the main videos width:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i logo.jpg -filter_complex ^
"[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw/5:h=ow/mdar[logo][main];[main][logo]overlay" ^
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: scale2ref h should be `ow/mdar`. `-1` will use the ref video's aspect ratio, which may be different.

Comment: @Gyan, true thank you, I tested it with a vertical main object and the overlay got messed up but with h=ow/mdar it works as expected.

Comment: @RicardoBohner when I use scale2ref, I kinda get the same results that I get with the normal scale.

Comment: @arya20 have you tried this with several videos and the logo still not consistent?

Comment: @RicardoBohner Sorry for the delay, I tried it again and it worked. Is there a way to set a minimum and maximum size?

Comment: Yes, with the min() and max() functions....

Comment: @RicardoBohner Sorry, but can you please show me an example?

Comment: @arya20 what would be your idea to use as a min and max value?